# Move marker from point A to point B by polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have polyline of tramways and more markers of tram. I found MovingMarker.js for animate markers' moving and leaflet.geometryutil.js for get closest point on polyline by point.
Need to get direction from point A to point B by polyline. Any libs?

Answer (score 0):

You mention MovingMarker.js and I think it has all you want to do.

[Example](http://ewoken.github.io/Leaflet.MovingMarker/) here.

For the line creation, you already have your two points, so you have both their coordinates, thus you'll be easily able to create a line between this two points, and run a moving marker on it using MovingMarker plug-in, making it start from point a coordinates to point b coordinates.

```
var line = L.line([L.latLng(/* point a lon*/, /* point a lat */), L.latLng(/* point b lon*/, /* point b lat */)]).addTo(map);
var marker = L.Marker.movingMarker([[/* point a lon*/, /* point a lat */],[/* point b lon*/, /* point b lat */]],
                    [20000]).addTo(map);
marker.start();
```